# How to use jinja2 to process dict and list in the case of nesting

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I tried to use python+jinja2 to deal with file, but jinja2 does not seem to be friendly to dict and list support. When using list and dict, an exception will be thrown:'xxx is undefined'. I tried to use the DebugUndefined parameter in jinja2, but it didn't work.
Example code:

```
from jinja2 import Template,DebugUndefined
template = Template("{{var1}}-{{ var2[0] }}",undefined = DebugUndefined)

rendered1 = template.render(var1=5)
print(rendered1)
# expect 5-{{ var2[0]}}
rendered2 = Template(rendered1).render(var2=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
print(rendered2)
# expect 5-a
```

the code can't run and thrown exceptions "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'var2' is undefined".The code about dict is the same.

```
from jinja2 import Template,DebugUndefined
template = Template("{{var1}}-{{ var2[Alice] }}",undefined = DebugUndefined)
rendered1 = template.render(var1=5)
print(rendered1)
# expect 5-{{ var2[Alice]}}
rendered2 = Template(rendered1).render(var2 = {'Alice': '2341', 'Beth': '9102', 'Cecil': '3258'})
print(rendered2)
# expect 5-2341
```

I noticed that flask+jinja2 can deal with this problem. Does flask changed some jinja2's code?
Ideas please? Newbie - be gentle. Thanks.